# Pasting arrow symbol from Outlook results in box instead of arrow

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, copy-paste

In Outlook, if you type `-->` or `<--` it transforms it into a symbol (maybe ANSI or UNICODE).

But I need to copy-paste those email messages into Chrome (into support tickets) and the arrows are lost, turning into square blocks.

Am I missing an encode pack? How can I fix this?

Comment: This problem is not specific to Chrome.  Try pasting it into IE, or Notepad for that matter, same deal.... Similar to the emitcons - Office shows a happy face, but everything else shows a `J`. The easiest way to deal with it may be to turn off the AutoFormatting of those arrows in Office, and/or search/replace them before copying.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I don't think that is a feasible option unless JBurace asks this of every single person emailing him/her.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I see your point, but you assume that the OP is getting tons of emails from many other people, when they made no such statement.

Comment: Related over on SO: [Copying wingdings (etc) from word documents to html text fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795687/copying-wingdings-etc-from-word-documents-to-html-text-fields)

Comment: Blog on the subject: [Don't use Wingdings](http://girtby.net/archives/2005/03/17/dont-use-wingdings/)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it doesn't have to be tons, asking just one person could create a negative connotation and cause the immediate questioning of OPs intellect for not being able to support such an "easy" thing in the mind of the average user. It just wouldn't be a good experience for either side no matter if JBruce's clients are internal or external.

Comment: You are assuming the emails are coming from people.  I get lots of emails from internal automated processes. Anyhow, it was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the support ticket page does not support all UTF-8 characters so when you paste into the textbox then that encoding is simply not understood.

Verify that the support ticket system encoding is compatible with the encoding of the email.

On http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref you can see `&rarr;` ( → ) is possibly the entity which you are looking for.

On the support ticket page, press Ctrl+u and you should pull up the HTML of the web page. Towards the top should be something like this `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

**Update**

According to http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html it looks like MS products use Windings font for those special chars which is not supported in HTML. Yes, those special chars do have equivalents but that would require a manual translation process or maybe there is a program which can do the conversion for you and then you would copy+paste from the program instead.

One solution could be to "Copy as plain text"

Comment: I have tried pasting it into Chrome's address bar, and I get the same issue. Nothing to do with the ticket page I'm on.

Comment: @JBurace I've looked further into the issue, please see the update.

Comment: Hmm. Outlook doesn't give me a "Copy as plain text", but if I "Paste as plain text" in Chrome I still get boxes.

Comment: @JBurace If you paste as plain text into MS Word or something then does the Windings still get used? Can you set your Outlook to render emails as plain text? Then you should have zero issues copy+pasting to the support ticket system.

Comment: Yeah it works in Word when pasted. I have no plans on changing my Outlook to plain text, as I do want to use those symbols for the recipients to see when sending emails.

Comment: @JBurace I honestly think there is no work-around for this Wingdings issue without manual intervention such as pasting the email into an interpreter which converts them into proper HTML entities.